# Segmentation Fault erorr

Tags: c

My program reads a file specified in the argument and prints out each string and its frequency inside the file.

The program works for this file: http://www.cse.yorku.ca/course/3221/dataset1.txt
but not this file: [http://www.cse.yorku.ca/course/3221/dataset2.txt](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/course/3221/dataset3.txt).

It gives `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error for the second file.

What could be wrong? Please help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef  struct {
    char  word[101];
    int   freq;
} WordArray;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


    WordArray *array = malloc(sizeof(WordArray));
    FILE *file;

    int i = 0;
    file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    char *str = (char*) malloc (108);

    while(fgets(str, 100, file) != NULL)
    {
        int pos = 0;
        char *word = malloc (100);

        while (sscanf(str, "%s%n", word, &pos ) == 1)
        {
            int j;
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                if (strcmp(array[j].word, word) == 0)
                {
                    array[j].freq = array[j].freq + 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (j==i)
            {
                array = (WordArray *) realloc (array, sizeof(WordArray) * (i+1));
                strcpy(array[i].word, word);
                array[i].freq = 1;
                i++;
            }

            str += pos;

        }
    }

    fclose(file);

    int k;

    for (k=0; k<i; k++)
    {
        printf("%s %d\n", array[k].word, array[k].freq);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: The return value for fopen is not checked, so a missing argument (argv[1]) is not detected.  This runs without errors for me, unless I leave out argv[1].

Comment: I edited my original question. Please reread.

Comment: Is there something wrong with you that you cannot **use a debugger**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several problems:

You increment str as part of the second loop and don't reset it.  I think this means your program is slowly walking through memory.

You fail to free word - probably better to allocate it outside the loop and on the stack but that won't cause a crash unless you input is huge and you run out of memory.

You don't need to cast result of malloc for modern compilers (yes, it used to be needed).

May want to check the results of malloc and realloc for safety.

I assume the first item is your problem.

Comment: Seems odd that not resetting `str` doesn't seem to be a problem with `dataset1.txt` for him?  I'd have thought it would trash the heap pretty good, too. Maybe never freeing `word` hides the problem by coincidence because only those leaked blocks are what happens to get trashed?

Comment: I did as you advised I move word outside the loop and I am now freeing str by using `str[0]='\0';` before the end of the first loop. But now nothing works. 
dataset1 gives the following error
`*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000000c533c0 ***`

I am not very good at C. Many of the concepts are new to me. Sorry for incompetence.

Comment: You don't "free" str in that way.  The problem I noted is that you keep incrementing str.  Instead, for your inner loop, create a variable "scan" that starts at "str" and then use it instead of str in the loop (both the scan and the str += pos.  Basically, you should never change str after it is created.  In reality, both word and str could be allocated on the stack instead of the heap (i.e. char word[100], str[100]).